# Problems with looping through array containing cURL options and setting them

Tags: php, curl

I'm making a library that allows a user to dynamically add/remove cURL options before a request is made. The foreach loop looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

// Cycle through each option and set them
foreach($setup['curl_options'] as $option => $value)
{
    echo '<p>' . $option . ' = ' . $value . '</p>';
    curl_setopt($ch, $option, $value);
}
```

The array key/values display correctly in the paragraphs, however when it comes to adding the values to the curl_setopt, I get the error:

`curl_setopt()` expects parameter 2 to be long, string given.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, $option, $value);
```

Let's say `$option` is 'CURLOPT_HEADER'. Your code boils down to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, 'CURLOPT_HEADER', $value);
```

the name of the constant is now a string, not an actual constant. What you need to do is store the value of what the constant represents in your array when you build it:

```
$setup['curl_options'][] = array('CURLOPT_HEADER', true); // wrong
$setup['curl_options'][] = array(CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // right
```

Comment: This seems to work :) However a funny thing pops up now when I loop the key/value pairs through paragraphs. If I loop through: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE, the $option parameter now contains numbers? 64 for HOST and 81 for PEER ?

Comment: That's the raw values of those constants. somewhere inside the php curl library, there's what amounts to `define('CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER', 81)`.

Comment: That's all those constant "strings" are - just a mapping from a friendly semi-readable string to the numbers that curl uses internally.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter (your `$option`) have to be a constant value.

Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php you have definition of all available constans.

If you already use that values of constans, you should parse it to `(long)` type.

If you just have names of that constans, use `constant($option)` but be sure that values are also uppercase and correct.

Comment: However, `constant()` simply returns the value of a constant. problem is that he's passing a string into the second argument `$option`, not the constant name itself.

Comment: Exacly. He should pass constant's value. When you use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true)`, you pass to function a value that is hidden in called constant. You can also look into PHP source code and check what value it is: `define ('CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER', 58);` and pass to the function just `58` instead of constant.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
curl_setopt($ch, constant($option), $value);
```

Comment: `eval` is evil. There is in PHP dedicated function for that operation called `constant()`.